# Get Text from Datagrid cell or Row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

Hello i am using the data grid to show an observable collection in WPF.
Now how can i  get the selected row text from the DataGrid so i can call a function.
Here is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,77,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="720" Width="664" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectedCellsChanged="dataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProjectName" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Path=ProjectName,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Path" MinWidth="460" Binding="{Binding Path=Path,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

How can i get the text from the selected cell or row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Items` collection you bind to is an `IEnumerable<T>`, you could cast the `SelectedItem` property of the `DataGrid` to `T`:

```
YourItemType obj = dataGrid.SelectedItem as YourItemType;
string name = obj.Name;
```

Or you could bind the `SelectedItem` property to a property of type `T`, just as you bind the `ItemsSource` property:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ...>
```

Answer (score 11):

As `WPF DataGrid` is more flexible than a `WinForms DataGridView`, gettings values seems difficult. So I made the below `static` *extension* methods/funcitons to get `SelectedRow`, `SelectedCell` & `SelectedCellValue`. Credits to some post I saw a while back in SO for `GetVisualChild` and some of the functions given below.

```
public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
     T child = default(T);
     int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
     for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
     {
         Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
         child = v as T;
         if (child == null)
         {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
         }
         if (child != null)
         {
            break;
         }
    }
        return child;
}
```

To get `SelectedRow`:

```
public static DataGridRow GetSelectedRow(this DataGrid grid)
{
    return (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem);
}
```

Gets the `DataGridRow` when you know the `RowIndex`:

```
public static DataGridRow GetRow(this DataGrid grid, int index)
{
     DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
     if (row == null)
     {
        grid.UpdateLayout();
        grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
        row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
     }
     return row;
}
```

Gets the `DataGridCell` when you have a `DataGridRow` and a `columnIndex`:

```
public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int columnIndex)
{
    if (row != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

        if (presenter == null)
        {
            grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[columnIndex]);
            presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
        }

        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex);
        return cell;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Gets the `DataGridCell` when you have a `DataGridRow` and a `columnName`:

```
public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, string columnName)
{
    int index = grid.Columns.Single(c => c.Header.ToString().ToUpper() == columnName.ToUpper()).DisplayIndex;
    return GetCell(grid, row, index);
}
```

Gets the `DataGridCell` when you have a `rowIndex` and a `columnIndex`:

```
public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, int row, int column)
{
     DataGridRow rowContainer = grid.GetRow(row);
     return grid.GetCell(rowContainer, column);
}
```

Gets the `DataGridCellValue` when you have a `DataGridRow` and a `ColumnName`:

```
public static string GetCellValue(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, string columnName)
{
    int index = grid.Columns.Single(c => c.Header.ToString().ToUpper() == columnName.ToUpper()).DisplayIndex;
    DataGridCell dgc = GetCell(grid, row, index);
    string str = Convert.ToString(((TextBlock)dgc.Content).Text);
    return str;
}
```

Gets the `DataGridCellValue` when you have a `rowIndex` and a `ColumnName`:

```
public static string GetCellValue(this DataGrid grid, int rowIndex, string columnName)
{
     DataGridRow row = grid.GetRow(rowIndex);
     int columnIndex = grid.Columns.Single(c => c.Header.ToString().ToUpper() == columnName.ToUpper()).DisplayIndex;

     DataGridCell dgc = GetCell(grid, row, columnIndex);
     string str = Convert.ToString((TextBlock)dgc.Content);
     return str;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to understand how one might go about implementing what you have posted above. Adding the code you posted into MainWindow.xaml.cs yields `Extension method must be defined in a non-generic class`. I have clearly missed something in my understanding of the implementation of this. I wonder if you would be able to explain in further detail? This is all pretty new to me.

Comment: So you know what `static` classes are?

Comment: Yes, I understand static classes.

Comment: Make a public `static` class, put the above codes in them and then use the functions mentioned above using `.` operator on your DataGrid :) Remember whenever you see an error that states `Extension method must be defined in a non-generic class`, it's because of the same reason as this.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll try that

Comment: This all makes sense so far, how do I access the returned object, so far I have: `DataGridRow t = dataGridTools.GetRow(endpoints, currentRowIndex);` I am currently returning System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow via t.ToString() but I am missing the correct way to address each object I believe

Comment: I'm not in-front of my pc right now, but I do believe you can access items stored in the  `DataGridRow` by `t.Item`. Further there may be a property `ItemArray` which might contain all the data that belongs to the row. While debugging, use IntelliSense(the popup which you get), navigate through it for the said properties. Also FWIW, `.ToString()` is returning the object type, this is not what should be used here

Comment: Thank you for your assistance :) I think I'll be able to work through it now.  @o_O

Answer (score 0):

You should use the default CollectionView for your data source.  Assumed it is called Items, you can use:

```
var cv = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);
var currentItem = (YourItemType)cv.CurrentItem;
```