# Migrating from Windows Forms to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

While migrating from Windows Forms to WPF, Some Data Grid properties are not accessible. I have tried finding out equivalent properties of Data grid in WPF, but did not find a solution.

```
    private void goTo_Click(Object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  _contraGrid.SelectedRows=((DataTable)_contraGrid.DataSource).Rows[2];

  try
    {
      int rowIndex = 0;
      foreach(DataGridRow r in _contraGrid.Items)
      {
        if(r.Cells["Contraaccount"].Value.ToString()==txtContraAcc.text)
        {
          rowIndex = r.Index;
        }
        _contraGrid.ClearSelection();
        _contraGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
        _contraGrid.FirstDisplayedScrolllingRowIndex = rowIndex;
        _contraGrid.Focus();
      }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    }
    }
}
```

Properties like SelectedRows,cells,rows are not found in the properties of WPF Data Grid. What can i use in place of that to perform the above functionality?

Comment: Please see [Get Text from Datagrid cell or Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956025/get-text-from-datagrid-cell-or-row/45956589#45956589)

Comment: It's rather pointless coming to a WPF forum and complaining that you can't do things exactly as you can in winforms - the two platforms are often very different in the way that they work. What is the exact operation that you're trying to perform - there's probably a straightforward solution, you just need to get you head out of the "winforms way" of doing things.

Comment: if you're migrating to wpf, you should also think about implementing MVVM design pattern (if not done) which is pertinent in most of the case and suits WPF very well.

Comment: In general, that code will have no useful parallel.  Your datasource would be bound to the grid, and you would use abstracted objects to get at the data.  Direct row/column access is not the best way in WPF.